# What is the shape a pair of constant angle scissors?

Tags: geometry

We know that a pair of scissors is hard to use at maximum opening angle, because the force from the blades pushes the object away from the scissors and the actual cutting force is reduced.

If we would design a pair of (simple, two-piece, with one point of rotation) scissors whose blades have a limited maximum incident angle, or even better, a constant incident angle, then what shape does it look like? Does it have a mathematical form?

[image: garden scissors]

[image source amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07763PY6Y)

Comment: You can cut any shape you like for the "incident curve" and get any set of incidence angles desired.

Comment: Maybe one straight blade through the pivot, with a logarithmic spiral blade centred at the pivot? Or two logarithmic spiral blades?

Comment: @abiessu Indeed, the incident track is an open end, so this problem has infinite number of solutions. Essentially we must manually choose the shape of one blade, e.g. the thumb blade, then design the secondary blade according to that.

Comment: You might be interested by this [reference](https://www.matec-conferences.org/articles/matecconf/pdf/2018/34/matecconf_ifcae-iot2018_03065.pdf) unfortunately very poorly written.